# How Update psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-13

For some reason I have `PostgreSQL` version 13 installed, but my `psql` is version 10.  How can I fix this?

```
[Tue Dec 27 22:09:13 user3@server_f ~] /usr/bin/psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.21
```

Comment: Which version of Linux are you running?

Comment: NAME="AlmaLinux"
VERSION="8.7 (Stone Smilodon)"
ID="almalinux"
ID_LIKE="rhel centos fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.7"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="AlmaLinux 8.7 (Stone Smilodon)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
LOGO="fedora-logo-icon"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:almalinux:almalinux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://almalinux.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.almalinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.almalinux.org/"

ALMALINUX_MANTISBT_PROJECT="AlmaLinux-8"
ALMALINUX_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8.7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="AlmaLinux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.7"

Comment: `sudo yum install postgresql` and not `postgresql-server` - that will get you the latest client!

Comment: Even better, uninstall the v10 packages.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no v10 packages were installed.  This box is not 3 months old.  Question remains though...this box is the db server, not the client alone.

Comment: Think. If PostgreSQL v10 were never installed, how could it be there?

Comment: @laurenzalbe Yes - uninstall current client first - should have had that!